# Current time plus one for date validation?

Tags: php

I'm having issues with a booking system that i'm trying to customize. It seems that the validation doesn't work on the current date and time if i select the current day.

The validation is a as following.

```
if (strtotime($str) < time()) {
```

But that doesn't allow me to book on the current date, even if the time is over current time, not sure if i should add + one to the validation or what. Any ideas would be very helpful.

Here is the full function.

```
public function _validate_date($str) {
    if (strtotime($str) < time()) {
        $this->form_validation->set_message('_validate_date', 'Date must be after today, you can only make future reservations!');
        return FALSE;
    } else {
        return TRUE;
    }
}
```

Comment: Code looks good to me..

Comment: $str  = selected date and time.

Comment: But the issue is that it doesn't work on current date for some weird reasons. So now it's 09:33 and if i select date today and 10:30 it doesn't work, or any other time today, but tomorrow works just fine.

Answer (score 1):

Try the following solution:

```
$datetime1 = new DateTime($str);
$datetime1->setTime(0, 0, 0);
$datetime2 = new DateTime();
$datetime2->setTime(0, 0, 0);

//get the diff.
$diff = $datetime2->diff($datetime1);
$days = (int) $diff->format("%R%a");

if ($days < 0) {
    echo 'past days';
} elseif ($days == 0) {
    echo 'today';
} else {
    echo 'future days';
}
```

A working example you can find here: https://3v4l.org/QQ4Pu

**Your function with the new solution:**

```
public function _validate_date($str) {
    $datetime1 = new DateTime($str);
    $datetime1->setTime(0, 0, 0);
    $datetime2 = new DateTime();
    $datetime2->setTime(0, 0, 0);

    //get the diff.
    $diff = $datetime2->diff($datetime1);
    $days = (int) $diff->format("%R%a");

    if ($days <= 0) {
        $this->form_validation->set_message('_validate_date', 'Date must be after today, you can only make future reservations!');
        return false;
    } else {
        return true;
    }
}
```

And a working example of your function: https://3v4l.org/HPTVF

Comment: Hey, just tried this "Your function with the new solution:" but that allows be also to book on dates before today, such as yesterday etc.

Comment: see my update now - if you want to allow today too you have to replace the `<=` with `<`

Answer (score 0):

If you want check, that current time is not higher current date, try this:

```
if (strtotime($str) <  strtotime(date('Y-m-d 23:59:59')) {
```